# JS: Map the inside of Array to a range of two dates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have calendar like this:

```
const calendar = [{
  "Title": "Go Shopping",
  "dates": [ 
  {
  "DateBeginn": "19.02.2021",
  "DateEnd": "22.02.2021",
  "Where": "Supermarket",
  },
  {
  "DateBeginn": "23.02.2021",
  "DateEnd": "23.02.2021",
  "Where": "Biomarket"
  }]
  }]
  
 const calendarData = calendar.map(main => main.dates.map(d => ({
  Title: main.Title,
  DateBeginn: d.DateBeginn,
  DateEnd: d.DateEnd,
  Where: d.Where,
  
 }))).flat()
  console.log(calendarData)
```

This puts something like this out:

```
  [
      {
        "Title": "Go Shopping",
        "DateBeginn": "19.02.2021",
        "DateEnd": "22.02.2021",
        "Where": "Supermarket"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Go Shopping",
        "DateBeginn": "23.02.2021",
        "DateEnd": "23.02.2021",
        "Where": "Biomarket"
      }
    ]
```

Now what i would like to have is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Title": "Go Shopping",
    "DateBeginn": "19.02.2021",
    "DateEnd": "22.02.2021",
    "Where": "Supermarket"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Go Shopping",
    "DateBeginn": "20.02.2021",
    "DateEnd": "22.02.2021",
    "Where": "Supermarket"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Go Shopping",
    "DateBeginn": "21.02.2021",
    "DateEnd": "22.02.2021",
    "Where": "Supermarket"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Go Shopping",
    "DateBeginn": "22.02.2021",
    "DateEnd": "22.02.2021",
    "Where": "Supermarket"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Go Shopping",
    "DateBeginn": "23.02.2021",
    "DateEnd": "23.02.2021",
    "Where": "Biomarket"
  }
]
```

That means i would like to map the inside of dates[{}] to a range of two dates if the difference is bigger than 1 day. In this example: Get the date range from 19.02.2021 to 22.02.2021 get every date and then create a new entity for each date. Then i would like to map the contents of the date array to each entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concisely add days and format them with Moment, and push the formatted strings to an array. Once the formatted string is equal to the `DateEnd`, you can map and return the array of day strings:

```js
const calendar = [{
    "Title": "Go Shopping",
    "dates": [{
        "DateBeginn": "19.02.2021",
        "DateEnd": "22.02.2021",
        "Where": "Supermarket",
    },
    {
        "DateBeginn": "23.02.2021",
        "DateEnd": "23.02.2021",
        "Where": "Biomarket"
    }
    ]
}]

const format = 'DD.MM.YYYY';
const calendarData = calendar.flatMap(main => main.dates.flatMap(d => {
    const momentObj = moment(d.DateBeginn, format);
    const endDateStr = d.DateEnd;
    const dateStrs = [d.DateBeginn];
    while (momentObj.format(format) !== endDateStr) {
        momentObj.add(1, 'days');
        dateStrs.push(momentObj.format(format));
    }
    return dateStrs.map(dateStr => ({
        Title: main.Title,
        DateBeginn: dateStr,
        DateEnd: dateStr,
        Where: d.Where,
    }));
}));
console.log(calendarData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is this scalable with big arrays? (thinking about cpu usage)

Comment: You might be able to increase performance by a bit by using the native Date instead of Moment, or by pushing to an outer array instead of `flatMap`, and by using a `for` loop - but it almost certainly won't matter, since the overall computational complexity will be the same. The code is not unnecessarily computationally complex, so it should be fine to use. Computers today are *fast*, unless you have like 100,000 items to create, it shouldn't matter

Comment: Amazing, how would you do this with native dates, since the format i am getting from my server is like 2021-03-12T00:00:00.000Z anyways

Comment: Pass the string into `new Date`, use the Date methods to retrieve the parts of the date (like `.getDate`), or use `.toISOString` and a regex to extract the parts you need. Increment the date by using `.setDays`

Comment: Like this?

const calendarData = calendar.flatMap(main => main.dates.flatMap(d => {
  const momentObj = new Date(d.DateBeginn);
  const endDateStr = d.DateEnd;
  const dateStrs = [d.DateBeginn];
  while (momentObj !== endDateStr) {
      momentObj.getDays(1);
      dateStrs.push(momentObj);
  }

Comment: It's not a Moment object anymore, it's a Date object, and it won't ever be `===` to a string anyway. Just stick with Moment, it's a lot easier

Comment: Ok got it. Changed it a little bit and now its working in my application as expected! Thanks again